# Awarding "part points"

Tags: discussion, support

I've put up a bounty on a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42018/determining-natural-origin-for-a-geotiff-file-lambert-conic), which got one response (not addressing the question). I'm reluctant to award the full points because it doesn't really answer the question. However I would like to award "something" for bothering to answer at all. Is there a way I can manually award some of the points without agreeing that this is an OK answer?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Added link to question.

Answer (score 3):

It will automatically get half of the bounty if it has received 2 upvotes and is the highest rated answer, without any action on your part. See the FAQ: https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

If it's not a good answer then it probably shouldn't receive a bounty just for posting. Community voting will generally decide whether it's a good answer or not.

Comment: It got one upvote and one downvote.

Comment: If the downvote is your own you might be able to change it back to an upvote to get to the 2 upvote mark. Then again [you might not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited), unless the answer is edited. Otherwise I think it would be up to the community to upvote it.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't want to upvote it just for points awards, because I'm trying to encourage / thank the poster, without making this a "good answer". I do see the contradiction here though.